# big double vectors in C++

Tags: linux, c++11, vector

I have   vector a(8000000000);
So 8000000000*8/1024/1024/1024=7.45Gb , so I need 7.45Gb RAM in order my program with this huge size to work, and I have that RAM in my computer but it doesn't work, WHY?

It compiles, but when I run, it gives error 
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
   what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What vector do you use?  Is there overhead?  Do you need contiguous memory?

Comment: Could you provide the actual code you are using to allocate that vector?

Comment: Also which environment is it? Windows? *nix? Which compiler (so that we can help you with the flags, if needed)

Comment: Imagine you have a vehicle that occupies 10 places in a car park. There's a car park with 15 free spaces. But you still can't park! Why? Because there isn't a single gap big enough. Computer memory is like that.

Comment: I'm using double vector, I just write vector<double> a(8000000000); then just cout<<a[0]<<endl;  That's all , I just wanted to check if it works , but seems it doesn't work , BUT MY RAM is much more than 8 gb

Comment: Do you have a requirement to reserve "statically" the memory for your vector? .. I mean, couldn't you start with a small vector and then reserve/resize space as you need it. Other alternative would be  dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: But there's so big RAM , 1) how do you think why I can't use to store 8*10^9 double elements?   2)  You mean to take vector<double> a(500); then a.resize(8000000000); ?

Answer (score 4):

2 things MUST be true for your program to work correctly:

- The OS has to be 64-bit (which is what you are presumably running on, otherwise you'd be limited to 3GB RAM)
- Your program **must** be built as a 64-bit application so it can actually address that much memory

For Windows MSVC solution/project make sure to follow the steps in this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2k70f3s.aspx article to set up for 64-bits.

For SunOS follow this article: http://www.well.com/~jax/rcfb/solaris_tips/build_gcc_3.0_64bit.html

And also for any other platform/compiler you should be able to pull the documentation via Google, of course

Comment: What it means , program must be built as a 64-bit application

Comment: Yes, it must be 64-bit. Running a 32-bit application on a 64-bit platform still limits its memory access to 32-bit/pointer (which is at most 4GB) so the application has to be built to use 64-bit pointers to address the memory beyond the 32-bit limit